# Write integer as well as float values to a text file

Tags: numpy, file, integer

Following is the code I am using to generate a list and write it to a text file:

```
import numpy as np

c = 0
a = []

for i in range(1, 16,1):
    b = i/10
    c += 1
    a.append([c,b])        

np.savetxt('test.txt', a, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")
```

When the `list a` is printed, the values taken by `c` are integers. However, when the `list a` is written to a file, `c` becomes float. Is it possible to append float and also integer to a text file using `numpy.savetxt`?

Comment: `savetxt` writes values from `np.array(a)`.  It's a numpy writer.  There is a `csv` module that can help with lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the format of each value. In your case where `np.array(a)` produce a 2D array with 2 columns:

```
np.savetxt('your_file.txt',a,delimiter=' ',fmt='%d %f')
```

Where `fmt = '%d %f'` correspond to an integer followed by a float.

The `.txt` file now contains:

```
1 0.100000
2 0.200000
3 0.300000
4 0.400000
5 0.500000
6 0.600000
7 0.700000
8 0.800000
9 0.900000
10 1.000000
11 1.100000
12 1.200000
13 1.300000
14 1.400000
15 1.500000
```